# Как лучше реализовать выбор нескольких объектов в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, select, checkbox

Здравствуйте. 
Пытаюсь реализовать добавление рецептов на сайте с выбором уже добавленных продуктов в базу данных. 
Естественно, продуктов можно выбрать несколько, но база предполагается большая, поэтому попала в небольшой тупик из-за отсутствия опыта. 
Не могу придумать, **как удобнее для пользователя** будет реализовать выбор этих продуктов.

Может есть какой-то select с поиском в yii2?

Или лучше сделать gridView, в котором можно будет выбирать несколько продуктов?(а при перелистывании страниц не сбросятся ли данные?)

Или есть более удобные способы, которые не пришли мне в голову.. 
Посоветуйте, пожалуйста))

Comment: Создайте таблицу для хранения выбранных товаров.При выборе того или иного товара добавляйте их в эту таблицу.Потом делайте с ним что угодно

Comment: Ну да, наверное, своеобразная "корзина" будет привычна и удобна для пользователей)

Comment: И еще и даст больше гибкости,и оптимально.В корзине товаров будет меньше чем в основной таблице.и да в таблице для корзины храните id  а не весъ товар.Легче и быстрее сделать выборку товаров по id

Comment: Само-собой id, благодарю) как-раз позволит удобно указывать граммовку и переходить к дальнейшему заполнению остальных полей

Comment: Вот вам SQL запрос который поможет вам в дальнейшем `SELECT p.name,p.price 
FROM products p
INNER JOIN baskets b
ON b.product_id = p.id`